# Show text 3 words at atime

Tags: button

I want to show 3 words at a time from some textfile. At a specified rate select time 1/100 to 300 sec).

I also want a pause button( eg ENTER) and a resume button (ENTER)

f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
for x in f:
  print(x)
input()
f.close()

The speed of display and the pause / resume buttons are a problem.
Request for and welcome any help

thanks

Comment: Still waiting for assistance :)

Comment: There's be no response to the question